# In App Purchase: Add transaction observer when application launch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I found this in documentation :

"Your application should add the observer when your application launches. The App Store remembers queued transactions even if your application exited before completing all transactions. Adding an observer during initialization ensures that all previously queued transactions are seen by your application."

But can I know if I add the observer when application launches (means apply addTransactionObserver method inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method), where and when can I remove the observer? Normally where you all add the observer?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: no need to remove? I am not sure about that...

Comment: Just stay as an observer for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The observer should be removed or it will cause issues. In my case I was repeatedly prompted to login every time the app was started.

Here are Apple's notes with more details on the subject. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2387/_index.html

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{   
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self.storeManager]; 
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self.storeManager];
}
```